# If URL contains X echo Y, elseif URL

Tags: php, strpos

I want to echo out different classes in a div depending on the URL. It's for a localized wordpress theme where a div will be using a different background depending on which site you are on.

```
<?php 
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/language/no') !== false) 
    {
        echo 'class="project_decal_no"';
    } 
    elseif (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/language/en') !== false) 
    {
        echo 'class="project_decal_en"';
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'class="project_decal"';
    }
?>
```

Am I on the right path with this? What should change to make it work?

Comment: `it doesn't really seem to work` is ambiguous .. what exactly is the error

Comment: Is this class set based on *site* or *language*? If the latter, you likely don't need PHP at all.

Comment: That code performs well, please clarify what is failing for you..

Comment: Does `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contain one of those sub-strings?

Comment: Hm, it is working for me on my testsite, but when I do the changes on the live site, they all get the decal from the else-statement. I did change the checked URL:s. If there is no fail in my code then I guess it must be something else!

Answer (score 2):

If it's for a theme, your `/language/en` isn't likely in the URL - it's likely just a directory path which would change regardless of the URL itself. Keep in mind that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is the text that appears in the address bar of the browser - so for this page `strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/questions/12825137') !== false` would be true.

Comment: Yes I realise that. My domain is: 'www.myproject.com/' and 'language/en' added to that in the case of english. Also I realise that !== is the same as "not false", so you can see my decals get the suffix of their proper language. 

Thanks anyway!